# Google cloud composer 'AirflowException: Celery command failed on host' error on cloud logging

Tags: airflow, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-composer

When examining the error messages in the Cloud Logs,
it appears that the 'Celery command failed on host' error is persistently generated, and simultaneously, the `ValueError: <object object at ~> is not a valid _MethodDefault` error is also occurring.

This error seems to be originating from the airflow-worker GKE node.

There are not error in composer UI, and task was running successfully.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/executors/celery_executor.py", line 130, in _execute_in_fork
    args.func(args)
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/cli/cli_parser.py", line 52, in command
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/utils/cli.py", line 108, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/cli/commands/task_command.py", line 399, in task_run
    _run_task_by_selected_method(args, dag, ti)
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/cli/commands/task_command.py", line 193, in _run_task_by_selected_method
    _run_task_by_local_task_job(args, ti)
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/cli/commands/task_command.py", line 252, in _run_task_by_local_task_job
    run_job.run()
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/jobs/base_job.py", line 258, in run
    self._execute()
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/jobs/local_task_job.py", line 181, in _execute
    self.handle_task_exit(return_code)
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/jobs/local_task_job.py", line 213, in handle_task_exit
    self.task_instance.schedule_downstream_tasks()
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/utils/session.py", line 75, in wrapper
    return func(*args, session=session, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 2561, in schedule_downstream_tasks
    partial_dag = task.dag.partial_subset(
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/models/dag.py", line 2202, in partial_subset
    dag.task_dict = {
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/models/dag.py", line 2203, in <dictcomp>
    t.task_id: _deepcopy_task(t)
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/models/dag.py", line 2200, in _deepcopy_task
    return copy.deepcopy(t, memo)
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/copy.py", line 153, in deepcopy
    y = copier(memo)
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/models/baseoperator.py", line 1161, in __deepcopy__
    setattr(result, k, copy.deepcopy(v, memo))
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/copy.py", line 172, in deepcopy
    y = _reconstruct(x, memo, *rv)
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/copy.py", line 264, in _reconstruct
    y = func(*args)
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/enum.py", line 339, in __call__
    return cls.__new__(cls, value)
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/enum.py", line 663, in __new__
    raise ve_exc
ValueError: <object object at ~> is not a valid _MethodDefault
```

Is there a way to resolve these error messages on the Composer's worker GKE node?

Google Cloud Composer Image Version : composer-2.1.14-airflow-2.5.1

Resolving the error message.